# Is a cross platform ( compiles and runs on OS X and Linux) GUI application written in Apple Swift Language implementable?

Tags: linux, swift, macos

As Apple released Swift language as open source , and now the 2.2 snapshot  runs on OS X and Ubuntu 64-bit; I would like to ask :

Is possible to implement a GUI application, that compiles and runs with the same code   on both of OS X and  Linux  programmed using Swift Language? Cocoa-based GUI Application is not an answer as Cocoa is supported on OS X only, so it won't compile on Linux.

Comment: That would have been awfully fast considering it's less than 48 hours since the announcement.  It does sound like a wonderful project for you to start, however. :)

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, the GNUstep team is working on making Swift bindings available, at which point that would be the natural choice, allowing you to maybe share some of your UI code between OS X and Linux.  For now, though, you'll either have to use one of the existing Linux UI libraries or be patient.

Comment: That is great news that GNUstep is interested in offering GUI bindings for swift language.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no GUI library released along with the Linux port of Swift.  Of course, one can use a library such as Qt with Swift, since Qt is a C++ library, and Swift can be relatively easily integrated with C/C++ code.  However, there is nothing new here: previously one could write portable applications using Qt in C and C++ that would run on Linux and Mac OS X.

What Swift brings to the table is an ability to write software for the Linux platform using a more succinct, higher-level language.  The downside is that Swift is likely to be of limited use on Linux without integration with legacy C/C++ libraries, and that integration can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Is there a Qt binding for swift language?